# Stopping Form to be submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which on submit should see if the text area has no text or the place holder text.

iif it does it shouldn't submit it. something like validation. I am not able to stop the form submission.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        target: '.user-status',
        // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        // pre-submit callback 
        success: showResponse,
        // post-submit callback 
        // other available options: 
        //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        resetForm: true // reset the form after successful submit 
        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    };

    $('#updateStatus').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false; // prevent a new request
    });

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

        var textbox = $('#StatusMessageMessage').val();
        if ((textbox == '') || (textbox == "What have you been eating ?")) {
            alert(text);
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', true);
        }

    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    statusMEssagebox();


});



function statusMEssagebox() {
    var textholder = $('#StatusMessageMessage').val();

    $('#StatusMessageMessage').focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == textholder) $(this).val("");

        $(this).animate({
            "height": "48px",
        }, "fast");
        $('.share').slideDown("fast");
        $(this).TextAreaExpander(48, 75);

    });

    $('#StatusMessageMessage').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(textholder);
            $('.share').slideUp("fast");
            $(this).animate({
                "height": "18px",
            }, "fast");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the jquery form plugin to ajaxify your form. There's an [example](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#validation) in the documentation illustrating how to achieve this in an elegant way. You don't need to subscribe for the `.submit` event of the form and manually submit it using `.ajaxSubmmit`. You could simply try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#updateStatus').ajaxForm({ 
        beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
            var value = $('#StatusMessageMessage').val();
            if (value == '' || value == 'What have you been eating ?') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. so i should place it on submit not on click ? will try

Comment: No, not on submit, nor on click. In should be in `$(document).ready` as in my example. You are simply declaring that `updateStatus` will be an ajax form meaning that when the form is submitted it will send an ajax request instead of a normal request. We are also subscribing to the `beforeSubmit` event which allows us to cancel the submission if there's a validation error.

Comment: it is inside document ready. i have edited the code. now when the validation fails its sending a normal request instead of ajax. :(

Comment: In your example you are subscribing for .submit event of the form which is not what I suggested. In my example I am calling `.ajaxForm` in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: ouch. got it. just curious. whats the advantage ?

Comment: What's the advantage of what over what?

Comment: .submit over directly calling .ajaxForm.. i tried this $('#updateStatus').ajaxSubmit(options); but the ajax stopped working now :(

Comment: There are two possibilities: `.submit` with `.ajaxSubmit` and `return false` or simply `.ajaxForm` which does all the three. So the advantage is writing less code which behind the scenes handles all that is needed for ajaxifying a form.

Answer (score 1):

You are using equality operator rather than comparison.

This:

```
if ((textbox = '') || (textbox = "What have you been eating ?")) {
Problem -----^
```

Should be:

```
if (textbox == '' || textbox == "What have you been eating ?") {
```

---

You may also want to see how the submit form via Ajax using jQuery:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: i changed that. still it doesnt stop the form to submit via normal submission (trying ajax here)